# Change color of h value

Tags: c++, opencv, hsv

I set my mask from BGR2HSV. I have my image:

[image: mask.png]

How I can change the white color in the mask?  So I want to change the white parts with other colors.

```
Mat mask;
mask = imread("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\...\\mask.png");
if (!img.data)
{
    cout << "Could not find the image";
    return -1;
}

cvtColor(mask, mask, COLOR_BGR2HSV);



cvtColor(mask, mask, COLOR_HSV2BGR);


imshow("Ergebnis", mask);
waitKey(0);
```

Comment: I use python not c++ so i can't share any code. since you are looking for white pixels to change, in HSV that means V is 255. so find pixels where the 3rd value == 255, then set the first value to whatever H you want

Answer (score 2):

Between two `cvtColor` functions, you need to split the image into its 3 channels with [`split`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga8027f9deee1e42716be8039e5863fbd9). Looking at [the conversion between RGB and HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_RGB), make S channel 0 and choose an H value between [0-180]. Then, [`merge`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga61f2f2bde4a0a0154b2333ea504fab1d) the channels back.

```cpp
cv::Mat hsv = mask.clone(); // from your code
std::vector<cv::Mat> hsv_vec;
cv::split(hsv, hsv_vec);
cv::Mat &H = hsv_vec[0];
cv::Mat &S = hsv_vec[1];
cv::Mat &V = hsv_vec[2];
S = 0;
mask = (V > 10); // non-zero pixels in the original image
H(mask) = your_H_value_here; // H is between 0-180 in OpenCV
cv::merge(hsv_vec, hsv);
mask = hsv; // according to your code
```

As a side note, I suggest using convenient names for variables.